# Searching for a CNN Time Series Prediction Tutorial

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm looking for instructions on how to make a regression time series prediction using a CNN. I want to implement a multi-step prediction for a univariate time series. I have read a few instructions but found nothing suitable for my dataset: one feature and around 400 observations.

Does anyone know an easily understandable and applicable code example for such a time series?

I would be very grateful for any help,

Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CNNs for sequence data can be a bit tricky to set up. In my experience, CNNs achieve results near RNNs (GRUs and LSTMs) but CNNs are far faster to compute.

First, make sure your data is shaped the way `Conv1D` expects: `(instances, time steps, predictors)`.

```
X_cnn = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1] // predictors, predictors)
```

Then, the syntax is:

```
model_cnn = Sequential()
model_cnn.add(layers.Conv1D(A, B, activation = 'relu', 
        input_shape = (X_cnn.shape[1], X_cnn.shape[2])))
model_cnn.add(layers.Flatten())
model_cnn.add(layers.Dense(1))
```

Where `A` is the number of neurons, and `B` is the number of time steps to consider. Note the `Flatten()` layer after the `Conv1D` layer. This should hopefully get you started.

Comment: So my trainset is now a float64 object with size (1,380,1) and my testset with (1,20,1) this should be correct data shape, right?
Is there a general recommendation number for A and B?
Do you know a good tutorial for this approach?

Comment: There are lots of good tutorials on how to use RNNs for data like yours but I don't know of any specifically for CNNs. I thought the code would allow you to adapt the RNN tutorials. Maybe start with: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Comment: Thanks you! But I already implemented a working example on RNN-LSTM for my data set. My Goal is to compare RNN-LSTM and CNN on that data set.
at first i thought i could reuse my 3d array from my RNN-LSTM example for the CNN approach but unfortunately that doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: I used your code and added the model.fit as follows: model_cnn.fit(x_train, x_test, epochs=1000, verbose=1). But I'm getting this error: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 380 target samples. Any idea?

Comment: The 3D array that works with the LSTM should work for the CNN; at least, it does for me. That error suggests your data isn't shaped correctly; Keras sees 1 X and 380 Y.

Comment: the shape function was wrong - now it works with your model! Thanks!